# Read a XML file using Pyspark in Databricks

Tags: xml, pyspark

I want to read XML file in Databricks using pyspark.
The xml code is given below

```xml
<BepVehicleTestResult>
<VehicleBuild>
   <ABS>
      <MaximumSensorSpeed Descritpion="Maximum allowable sensor speed" Units="MPH">7.0</MaximumSensorSpeed>      
      <MinimumSensorSpeed Description="Minimum allowable sensor speed" Units="MPH">3.0</MinimumSensorSpeed>      
      <RearSensorLoaction Descritpion="Location of Rear ABS Sensor" ValidTypes="Front,Rear">Front</RearSensorLoaction>      
      <SensorTestSpeed Description="Roll speed for the sensor test" Units="MPH">5</SensorTestSpeed>     
      <SensorTestStartDelay Units="mSec">3000</SensorTestStartDelay>   
   </ABS> 
   <Axle>MainAxle</Axle>   
   <BrakeDistance>
      <FrontMaximumStoppingDistance Units="Feet">42.65</FrontMaximumStoppingDistance>     
      <FrontMinimumStoppingDistance Units="Feet">5.0</FrontMinimumStoppingDistance>      
      <RearMaximumStoppingDistance Units="Feet">42.65</RearMaximumStoppingDistance>     
      <RearMinimumStoppingDistance Units="Feet">5.0</RearMinimumStoppingDistance>   
   </BrakeDistance>
```

Comment: Hi Sankar, seems you are the new user of SO. Please format the question accordingly, otherwise, it has a low chance to survive a moderation

Comment: Hi Alex. 
I have a xml file which is having multiple tags. So I would like to have pyspark code to read that.

Comment: But why you then cannot place it as the input? You can use wrap it with triple ticks, like ``` your data ``` to preserve formatting. I just did it for you )

Comment: Perhaps, this sample notebook might be a solution for you: https://github.com/raveendratal/PysparkTelugu/blob/master/Read_Write_XML_File.ipynb

Comment: Your XML misses closing `</BepVehicleTestResult>` and 
`</VehicleBuild>`

Comment: @ZygD Could you please refer this link for the whole code. https://github.com/sankarkumarazad123/xml/blob/main/MAT476124K0H11297.xml

Comment: Please review the link above. It seems someone had asked the same question before. Which makes this question a duplicate, so it should be closed, as it already has an answer elsewhere, just just need to study it.

Comment: @ZygD I saw the link above but is different. Could you at least once see my xml code.

Comment: @AlexanderVolok could you also please look at the xml code I provided in the link above.